# Can I update AMQP settings in runtime?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have specific requirements: needed application that can change connection settings and listened queues in runtime.

I want to use Spring AMQP abstractions: CachingConnectionFactory, DirectMessageListenerContainer, RabbitTemplate, AsyncRabbitTemplate that application will update in runtime.

CachingConnectionFactory - update address, username and password.
DirectMessageListenerContainer - update QueueNames.
Last ones - will not updated, but affected by ConnectionFactory.

Is it correct way? Or I should use base implementation with consumers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- stop all activity that uses the broker (listener containers, producers)
- `cachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection()`
- reconfigure connection factory
- add and remove queues to/from the containers
- start containers and producers

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.